# Is there any C++ code beautifuler plug-in for eclipse?

Tags: c++, eclipse, refactoring

I found a very tempting function in Netbeans, which is to re-factor or 'beautiful-ize' the c++ code according to some parameters, such as tab length, {'s position, etc

is there anything similar in Eclipse, which keyword should I google?

Comment: is the code formatter only for java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Go to your code window
- Right click
- Select "Source" then "Format"

This should reformat your code according to the options given in the Preferences => "C/C++" => "Code Style

Answer (score 1):

By using Code Formatter (Ctrl + Shift + F) you can indent the code following a predefined template. Go to Window -> Preferences -> Code Style.

Answer (score 0):

[CPPStyle](https://github.com/wangzw/CppStyle) plugin requires [cpplint.py](https://github.com/google/styleguide/tree/gh-pages/cpplint) and [clang-format](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html) and it simply works great. You may as well automatically format your code with google style while saving it. This can be done for all your projects at once, too.